# find first visible required drop-down which is empty in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried below code but its not working for drop-downs even thought both below drop-downs are at index 0, TIA.

**Design :-**

```
<select required="required" id="Countries">
   <option selected="selected" value="0">--Select--</option>
   <option value="27">UK</option>
   <option value="1">United States</option>
</select>

<select required="required" id="States">
   <option value>--Select--</option>
   <option value="1">Abc</option>
   <option value="2">Xyz</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:-**

```
var totalRequired_Empty = $('input:blank:not(:checkbox,:button,:radio),select option[value="0"],textarea:blank').filter('[required]:visible').length;
if (totalRequired_Empty > 0) {
 var firstRequired = $('input:blank:not(:checkbox,:button,:radio),select option[value="0"],textarea:blank').filter('[required]:visible:first');
```

Comment: Does jQuery support pseudo `:blank`? Because it throws an error for me and removing it makes your code work just fine

Comment: yes - : blank is working in my code

Comment: Please define "_not working_".

Comment: totalRequired_Empty  returns 0

Comment: I'd say your filter method is not working as intended. As soon as you targeting option there will be no matches for selector `[required]`... I'm also suspect filtering with `:visible` can also pose some problems

Answer (score 2):

May be it's an old way,but you can apply `$.each`:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[required]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() ==0 && $(this).val()!=='' && $(this).val()!=='undefined'){
      $(this).css({'background-color':'red'});
    }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required="required" id="Countries">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="27">UK</option>
  <option value="1">United States</option>
</select>

<select required="required" id="States">
  <option value>--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">Abc</option>
  <option value="2">Xyz</option>
</select>
```

Note:- You can change conditions  based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
   $('select[required]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'red' });
            }
    });
```